# DATA pattern in logstash - grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to understand the `DATA` pattern in grok plugin of logstash.
As per the documentation `DATA` matches as following:

> `DATA .*?` --> I interpreted it as anything with length 1 to n [Please
>   correct me if my understanding is wrong].

In my script, it fails to parse my input properly.
**Logstash conf:**

```
input{
file {
        path => ["/home/osboxes/logstash_conf/mydir/test_logs/*"]
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/home/osboxes/logstash_conf/mydir/.sincedb"
   }
}
filter{
        grok {
                match => { "message" => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timeStamp},%{DATA:ID},%{DATA:somedata}" }
        }
}
output {
   stdout {
        codec => json_lines
   }
}
```

**Input:**

```
2017-01-09 02:00:03.887,a,a
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "message": "2017-01-09 02:00:03.887,a,a",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2017-01-09T12:28:20.958Z",
    "path": "/home/osboxes/logstash_conf/mydir/test_logs/data",
    "host": "osboxes",
    "timeStamp": "2017-01-09 02:00:03.887",
    "ID": "a"
}
```

I expected the tag `somedata` will be filled with value [as it did for tag `ID`] but it is omitted from the output. Anyone please help me understanding the behavior of `DATA` pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*?` Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed. The fact that it can match **zero** times is the reason you don't see a result.

Written out, the problematic part looks like this:

`,(.*?),(.*?)` ( Capture groups added for readability)

This matches : `,a,`

1.Take the first `,` and match it.

2.Try to match `.*?` with as few as possible (character by character until pattern is valid) this matches the `a`

3.Try to match the next `,`. This suceeds so the first `.*?` is done.

4.Try to match `.*?`. Since this can match **zero** times it will do so and the matching is complete.

---

The simple solution to your problem is to add a `$` at the end of your pattern. `$` is a end of string anchor so your second `.*?` is forced to match the other `a`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case, is it reliable have `DATA` pattern or I need to look for other pattern? As you mentioned, it may match zero chars, in some cases it may skip the values which I indeed interested in...

Comment: @G.S You should be good to go if you terminate your pattern with a `$`. This will ensure that your second `DATA` __has__ to match something.

Comment: Understand. I am just worried about if the similar behavior happens for `DATA` in the middle. `$` can be used only for the last field. Not sure if the `DATA` may fail for the fields in middle. Just to ensure if it is reliable

Comment: @G.S If you really want to make sure your pattern works you can use Grokdebugger.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It is helpful. Just in case if anyone following this thread and want to debug - here is the grok online debugger - https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com